# Como fazer drilldown para a ficha do cliente e para a ficha do Artigo (V10)?

Tags: c#

Estou a tentar fazer o drilldown para uma manutenção no PRIMAVERA, como por exemplo a ficha do cliente ou artigo mas não estou a entender como fazer.

Na versão 9 creio que o metódo será algo do género:
`Motor.Comercial.Artigos.DrillDownArtigo...`

No entanto na V10 não consegui encontrar esta função.
Já procurei nos seguintes:
`Motor.Base.Artigo` e `Motor.Inventário`

Qual será o novo metodo para fazer drilldown para a Ficha do Artigo e também para a ficha do Cliente?

Tenho este código que funciona para fazer drilldown para Documentos de Venda e de Compra.

```
StdBESqlCampoDrillDown stdBESqlCampoDrillDown = new StdBESqlCampoDrillDown();
stdBESqlCampoDrillDown.ModuloNotificado = "GCP";
stdBESqlCampoDrillDown.Tipo = StdBESqlTipos.EnumTipoDrillDownListas.tddlEventoAplicacao;
stdBESqlCampoDrillDown.Evento = "GCP_EditarDocumento";

StdBEValoresStr stdBEValoresStr = new StdBEValoresStr();
stdBEValoresStr.InsereNovo("Modulo", modulo);
stdBEValoresStr.InsereNovo("Filial", codigoCliente);
stdBEValoresStr.InsereNovo("Tipodoc", tipodoc);
stdBEValoresStr.InsereNovo("Serie", serie);
stdBEValoresStr.InsereNovo("NumDocInt", numdoc);

PSO.DrillDownLista(stdBESqlCampoDrillDown, stdBEValoresStr);
```

Será agora algo relacionado para as Fichas de Artigo e de Cliente?

Obrigado.

Comment: Olá, neste projeto tens vários exemplos de como isto pode ser feito:
[PrimaveraSDK](https://github.com/PrimaverabssDeveloper/ERP10Extensibility/tree/master/Primavera%20SDK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá o Daniel Vieira tem razão, no [GitHub PRIMAVERABSS](https://github.com/PrimaverabssDeveloper) tens vários exemplos sobre esse tema, no entanto aqui fica a dica para as entidades.

```
  internal static void drillDownEntidade(StdBSInterfPub PSO, string categoria, string entidade)
    {
        StdBESqlCampoDrillDown campoDrillDown = new StdBESqlCampoDrillDown();
        StdBEValoresStr param = new StdBEValoresStr();

        campoDrillDown.ModuloNotificado = "GCP";
        campoDrillDown.Tipo = StdBESqlTipos.EnumTipoDrillDownListas.tddlEventoAplicacao;
        campoDrillDown.Evento = "GCP_MOSTRAMANUTENCAO";

        param.InsereNovo("Manutencao", categoria);
        param.InsereNovo("Chave", entidade);

        PSO.DrillDownLista(campoDrillDown, param);
    }
}
```